# Samba translates "::" in directory names to strange string

Tags: filenames, samba, file-transfer, compatibility

Samba automatically translates directory names containing `::` to some weird string, and there is no direct mapping to a Unix name.

Example: `ddrs04ia::ip76xddrshared_hiphdk_lay::ip76xddrshared_anamux8to1`
becomes `DUZSMU~9` in Windows.

Any way around this?

Comment: Not an answer, but it looks like [8.3 filenaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) is enabled somewhere: "To maintain backward-compatibility with legacy applications (on DOS and Windows 3.1), on FAT and VFAT filesystems an 8.3 filename is automatically generated for every LFN (Long File Name), through which the file can still be renamed, deleted or opened, although the generated name (e.g. OVI3KV~N) may show little similarity to the original."

Comment: Maybe because [Windows does not like `:` in filenames](https://superuser.com/a/1112140/432690).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this I am afraid. The reason is that `:` is forbidden character in path names on Windows while on unices it is not.

In Windows `:` is used for both "disk drive" delimitation and alternate data streams delimitation in filenames, while on unices it can be used freely.

Especially directory formats like `maildir(+)` and similar are impossible to express on windows.

Only solution is to never expose paths with `:` in names to windows world.